# Do selectors cause re-rendering on unrelated components in Redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am diving into Redux toolkit and made a simple project to understand its concepts better.

```
function App() {
 //..
 return(
  <UserList /> // uses submittedUserSelector
  <UserInformation /> // uses selectedUserSelector
 );
}
```

The basic idea is that you can either add a user to `UserList` or select one from the list which will be shown in `UserInformation`. Both the submitted and selected user are managed by different reducers in the same store.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer, // have submitted user selector
    user: userReducer // have selected user selector
});

// formReducer.tsx
 export const submittedUserSelector = (state:RootState)=>state.form.submittedUser; //object
// selectedUserReducer.tsx
 export const selectedUserSelector = (state:RootState)=>state.user.selectedUser; //object
```

[According to the official documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) and I quote:

> When an action is dispatched, useSelector() will do a reference
> comparison of the previous selector result value and the current
> result value. If they are different, the component will be forced to
> re-render. If they are the same, the component will not re-render.

So I was expecting that when I selected a user which dispatches an action in `userReducer`
would result in re-rendering `UserList` as well (as submittedUserSelector returns an object). That didn't happen, however.

Why? Does redux-toolkit figure out which components in the tree are using a particular selector and only evaluate those? Is that somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors will be called on every state change and **only** cause a component rerender if the selector result changes from the last render - so usually, unrelated components will not be rerendered.

Keep in mind that general React component rendering still applies - if a parent component rerenders, all child components will be rerendered.

This has nothing to do with redux-toolkit though - it is the normal behaviour of the react-redux hooks. See https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks